# Calling log4j logger in a java "Generic Class"

Tags: java, generics, log4j

When trying to add log4j logger to a Generic class, it does not generate logs.
This is the code used.

```
public class GenericClass<K extends Serializable, V extends Serializable> extends ... {
      public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenericClass.class.getName());
```

I am guessing the reason this code fails is because the class is not instantiated till runtime and the plain name that i have given no more resolves to the newly generated class.

Is there a way that generic classes can be logged at all?

Comment: Is there some relevant configuration (like a log4j.properties or logback.xml or something) that you can post to give us more information?

Comment: Why are you using getLogger(GenericClass.class.getName()) instead of getLogger(GenericClass.class)?

Comment: @ChristopherMartin my bad, every thing works fine. for some reason i freaked out. had put in wrong ear files on the server. sorry :-(. the getName() thing is just old habbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics have nothing to do with this.

At runtime, a logger by the name of `x.y.z.GenericClass` (`x.y.z` being the package in which `GenericClass` is located). If nothing is logged, then it's either because your application isn't logging anything, or your Log4J configuration is faulty.

To decide which one is true, add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to your server initialization parameters and give it a try.

Comment: my bad, every thing works fine. for some reason i freaked out. had put in wrong ear files on the server. sorry :-(